# Find the missing letter- Where does the correct letter come from

Tags: java

Theres a task to solve:

Write a method that takes an array of consecutive (increasing) letters as input and that returns the missing letter in the array.

You will always get an valid array. And it will be always exactly one letter be missing. The length of the array will always be at least 2.
The array will always contain letters in only one case.

Example:

['a','b','c','d','f'] -> 'e'
['O','Q','R','S'] -> 'P'

and the solution:

```
char[] test = {'a','b','c','d','f'};
        System.out.println(findMissingLetter2(test));
```

...

```
public static char findMissingLetter2(char[] array){
        char expectableLetter = array[0];
        System.out.println("ex letter is " + expectableLetter);
        for(char letter : array){
            System.out.println("letter is " + letter);
            if(letter != expectableLetter) break;
            expectableLetter++;
            System.out.println( "new ex num is " + expectableLetter);
        }
        return expectableLetter;
    }
```

and the console

```
ex letter is a
letter is a
new ex num is b
letter is b
new ex num is c
letter is c
new ex num is d
letter is d
new ex num is e
letter is f
e
```

the 'e' comes from the
char expectableLetter = array[0];
expectableLetter++;

but theres no letter 'e' in the array? So why does this solution work? How the terminal can print 'e' letter from the array, if theres no such letter there.

The console prints 'a' and not the ascii code 97 and so on

Comment: `expectedLetter` holds the value `100` which is the Unicode codepoint for `d`. Incrementing that by 1 using `++` will yield `101`, which happens to be `e`.

Comment: so char turn eveything into ascii code or what? why termial prints a and not 97?

Comment: Try `Integer.valueOf(array[0])` or `Character.getNumericValue(array[0])` if you want the ASCII code

Comment: `char` does not “turn anything” into ASCII, `char` is just a number (or bit pattern, as everything is). The terminal prints `a` because operations are typed, e.g. `print(char)` has a different behavior than `print(int)` even when passing the same number (or bit pattern). You can, for example, write `int i = 'a'; System.out.println(i);` and it will print `97`. And you can write `char c = 97; System.out.println(c);` and it will print `a`. Because, it’s not about the value but how it will be interpreted/ processed. Which is determined by the choice between `println(char)` and `println(int)`

Comment: …and `System.out.println(97 == 'a');` will print `true`

Comment: And as an added hint: Forget that "ASCII" even exists. It's almost entirely meaningless in todays IT system, except as a common ancestor of multiple other encodings. In most modern languages you handle Unicode codepoints or at least UTF-16 code units (which you could pretend are codepoints if you only care about the basic multilingual plane, a.k.a the lower 64k Unicode codepoints).

Comment: As an aside, in case of `char[] test = { 'i', 'j' };` the missing letter could be either `h` at the front or `k` at the rear. Your code prints `k`, which is one of the correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sliding window approach to compare the distance between the `curr` and the `prev` character in the array.

Just cast the result of `prev + 1` to a `char` to get the missing letter.

```java
public class CharArrayUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(findMissingLetter(new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'})); // 'e'
        System.out.println(findMissingLetter(new char[]{'O', 'Q', 'R', 'S'})); // 'P'
    }

    public static char findMissingLetter(char[] letters) {
        if (letters == null || letters.length < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide at least two letters");
        }
        char prev, curr;
        for (int index = 1; index < letters.length; index++) {
            prev = letters[index - 1];
            curr = letters[index];
            if (curr - prev == 2) {
                return (char) (prev + 1);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("The array is sequential");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what was asked. The OP already has working code.

Comment: Not relevant to the question but a different approach